# Does 'shorter frequency' mean it happens less often?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean ***friends laughed slightly less often than strangers***? I inferred it from the next passage, but I am not sure it does, because in light waves high frequency means short wavelength.

> In one example of the important role of laughter in social contexts,
> Devereux and Ginsburg(2001) examined frequency of laughter in matched
> pairs of strangers or friends who watched a humorous video together
> compared to those who watched it alone. The time individuals spent
> laughing was nearly twice as frequent in pairs as when alone.
> ***Frequency of laughing was only slightly shorter for friends than strangers.*** According to Devereux and Ginsburg(2001), laughing with
> strangers served to create a social bond that made each person in the
> pair feel comfortable. This explanation is supported by the fact that
> in their stranger condition, when one person laughed, the other was
> likely to laugh as well. Interestingly, the three social conditions
> (alone, paired with a stranger, or paired with a friend) did not
> differ in their ratings of funniness of the video or of feelings of
> happiness or anxiousness. This finding implies that their frequency of
> laughter was not because we find things funnier when we are with
> others but instead we are using laughter to connect with others.

[An Introduction to the Psychology of Humor](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=D8yGDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=Frequency%20of%20laughing%20was%20only%20slightly%20shorter%20for%20friends%20than%20strangers.%20According%20to%20Devereux%20and%20Ginsburg,%20laughing%20with%20strangers%20served%20to%20create%20a%20social%20bond%20that%20made%20each%20person%20in%20the%20pair%20feel%20comfortable.%20This%20explanation%20is%20supported%20by%20the%20fact%20that%20in%20their%20stranger%20condition,%20when%20one%20person%20laughed,&source=bl&ots=DoI_ac8mM-&sig=ACfU3U1UfzretipmGXtdtVx9SJJjAfKwCg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPwt3c-OL9AhVUFogKHcqQBggQ6AF6BAglEAM#v=onepage&q=Frequency%20of%20laughing%20was%20only%20slightly%20shorter%20for%20friends%20than%20strangers.%20According%20to%20Devereux%20and%20Ginsburg%2C%20laughing%20with%20strangers%20served%20to%20create%20a%20social%20bond%20that%20made%20each%20person%20in%20the%20pair%20feel%20comfortable.%20This%20explanation%20is%20supported%20by%20the%20fact%20that%20in%20their%20stranger%20condition%2C%20when%20one%20person%20laughed%2C&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

In this context, '*frequency*' means how often something happens. Often this would be measured by the intervals in between instances, but in the previous sentence, it states that the "*time individuals spent laughing*" is the measure, so 'shorter' means less laughter. That way of measuring may be a little unusual, but as this is more of a social science observation than about physical science I would not be over-critical of the use of language.

'Frequency' in the context of wavelength is spoken of as being 'higher' or 'lower' frequencies, which is one way you could recognise that this was not talking about physics (although wavelength itself can be shorter or longer).

Comment: It may be social science and possibly we should cut them some slack, but it's still poor English IMHO. I've never heard that phraseology before. It would be far better to say ""Frequency of laughing was only slightly **less /[more] than for ...**.